# Python: Msgpack-Numpy cannot handle my data?

Tags: python, numpy, datetime, serialization, msgpack

I am trying to use msgpack and msgpack-numpy to serialize some data. My code is as follows:

```
import msgpack
import msgpack_numpy
msgpack_numpy.patch()
print(products[0]['data']['AMAZON_time'])

def decode_datetime(obj):
    if b'__datetime__' in obj:
        obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(obj[b'as_str'].decode(), "%Y%m%dT%H:%M:%S.%f")
    return obj

def encode_datetime(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, datetime.datetime):
        obj = {'__datetime__': True, 'as_str':obj.strftime("%Y%m%dT%H:%M:%S.%f").encode()}
    return obj

with open('bookData.msgpack','wb') as outfile:
    msgpack.pack(products[0]['data']['AMAZON_time'],outfile,default=encode_datetime)

with open('bookData.msgpack','rb') as infile:
    data = msgpack.unpack(infile,object_hook=decode_datetime)
```

This throws the following error:

```
  ValueError: cannot create an OBJECT array from memory buffer
```

When printed, the object I am trying to store looks as follows:

```
[datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 23, 12, 44) datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 8, 6, 0)
 datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 8, 8, 28) datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 8, 10, 8)
 datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 8, 14, 56) datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 8, 21, 8)
 datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 8, 21, 56)
 datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 8, 23, 44) datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 9, 0, 36)]
```

However, if I print `products[0]['data']` I get sth containing the words `dtype=Object` (not sure if this is relevant, but I thought I'd mention it given the phrasing of the error).

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

EDIT: I don't know whether it is relevant, but I can save and load the same data with pickle.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue by hand-coding a translation function that saves a timestamp (as an integer) instead of a numpy array of datetime objects. I believe MSGPACK (even with the MSGPACK-NUMPY addition) is just not able to handle arrays of datetime objects, even with hand-coded decoders and encoders for datetime objects (the problem is with the numpy array of object types, not really with the datetime objects).